# Laravel 5.4 - "DB:raw()" using MySQL "CAST()" function

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to submit a `DB:raw()` query, to test the MySQL `CAST()` function.

My `Model` contains:

```
class User extend Model
{
   public static function myMethodDate()
   {
        $var = DB::select(
                  DB::raw("SELECT CAST('2017-05-24 13:38:35.471001' AS DATETIME(3)) AS arrival_time")
               );
        dd($var[0]->arrival_time);
   }
}
```

when I call the `myMethodDate()` method, It returns:

```
"2017-05-24 13:38:35"
```

but If I run It on MySQL shell:

```
mysql>
mysql> SELECT CAST('2017-05-24 13:38:35.471001' AS DATETIME(3)) AS arrival_time;
+-------------------------+
| arrival_time            |
+-------------------------+
| 2017-05-24 13:38:35.471 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

with "milliseconds".

Why the Laravel `DB:raw()` query does not report the MySQL `CAST()` output?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the solution to retrieve "as is" MySQL `CAST()` output:

```
class User extend Model
{
   public static function myMethodDate()
   {
        $var = DB::select(
                  DB::raw("SELECT CONVERT( CAST('2017-05-24 13:38:35.471001' AS DATETIME(3)), CHAR) AS arrival_time" )
               );
        dd($var[0]->arrival_time);
   }
}
```

and now the out, correctly, is `"2017-05-24 13:38:35.471"`

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the `DB:raw()` method, it is how `php` handles `DateTime`. If you call `format()` on the `DateTime`, you should be able to get the microseconds:

```
dd($var[0]->arrival_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u'));
```

Comment: I cannot get MySQL output "as is", without use format()?

Comment: Internally, `php` is using `format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` when you convert it to a string

Comment: I testing again and running `DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT '2017-05-24 13:38:36.471001' AS arrival_time" ));` it return correctly `"2017-05-24 13:38:36.471001"`. I think the problem is on MySQL `CAST()` function.

Comment: Because the query in your comment is returning it as a `string`, not `DateTime`

Comment: Yes, true! My point is to use MySQL CAST() function and retrieve the output. Converting it to string(), I get it. Thank you again for you answer, I understand the php automatic conversion for DateTime.